# Bootstrap input padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This Bootstrap code gives you a date input field. However it gives me a huge area to the right of the input field that is not used and can't be used. How can I get rid of that unused area ?

[image]

When in this exemple I put in two "xx" you can see that this area hides the text

[image]

Code :

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
    <label for="date_born">Date naissance</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="date_born">
        <input name="date_born" class="form-control" value="16/09/2016" placeholder="jj/mm/aaaa" type="text" id="date_born" data-bv-field="date_born">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about input right padding `.has-feedback .form-control {padding-right: 42.5px;}`  this comes from.less bootstrap by default `.form-control` Properties

try this

```
.has-feedback .form-control {padding-right:5px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to add a fixed width to the 'input-group' div, like

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
    <label for="date_born">Date naissance</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="date_born" style="width: 150px;">
    <input name="date_born" class="form-control" value="16/09/2016" placeholder="jj/mm/aaaa" type="text" id="date_born" data-bv-field="date_born">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```